# Map name to id in Meteor app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

In Meteor, I have already subscribed to a publications which publishes many documents from a collection. Each document has `_id` and `name`. I print all these documents somewhere in my app.

On some other place in my app I have some IDs. But instead of printing the ID, I want to print the name which corresponds to the id.

I could simply use

```
for (var i=0; i<idList.length; i++) {
  doc = CollectionName.findOne(idList[i]);
  console.log(doc.name);
}
```

but will this result in poor performance? I am thinking that since I have already subscribed to the entire collection, it wont cost more to perform a mongodb call for each id. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

On the client all your queries are made against the [MiniMongo](https://www.meteor.com/mini-databases) database (which is an client side in-memory replication of MongoDB) containing the documents published by the server. So it is really cost effective as you are searching for documents only on the client side without calling the server.

Concerning your code, I think the use of `find()` and then `map()` would be more effective:

```
var namesArray = CollectionName.find().map(function(document) {
  console.log(document.name);
  return document.name;
});
```

With `find()` you are doing only one query that returns a cursor, then the `map()` function will go through all the documents in the cursor and perform whatever operation you want with each document like printing the name in the console and returning it.
Also, all returned values will be added to a single array (here called `namesArray`) that you will be able to reuse somewhere else.

Comment: But how can I get the right element in `namesArray` based on the id?

Comment: ok I did not perfectly understand your question. If you want to fetch the name corresponding to a specific document `findOne()` is definitely the way to go, as it is made against Minimongo it is indeed cost effective.